# Is it possible to pass to lettuce redis library MasterSlave connection only slaves uris?

Tags: redis, lettuce

my aim is to add only slaves URIs, because master is not available in my case. But lettuce library returns

`io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Master is currently unknown: [RedisMasterSlaveNode [redisURI=RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=6382], role=SLAVE], RedisMasterSlaveNode [redisURI=RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=6381], role=SLAVE]]`

So the question is: Is it possible so avoid this exception somehow? Maybe configuration. Thank you in advance

UPDATE: Forgot to say that after borrowing object from pool I set `connection.readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE)` before running commands.

```
GenericObjectPoolConfig config = fromRedisConfig(properties);
List<RedisURI> nodes = new ArrayList<>(properties.getUrl().length);
for (String url : properties.getUrl()) {
  nodes.add(RedisURI.create(url));
}
return ConnectionPoolSupport.createGenericObjectPool(
        () -> MasterSlave.connect(redisClient, new ByteArrayCodec(), nodes), config);
```

Comment: Read about https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/release/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/ReadFrom.html#SLAVE_PREFERRED this is an option you pass to `MasterSlave.connect`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to set data, which is possible only with master node. So there is no problem with MasterSlave. Get data works perfectly